# CUDA: cudaMemcpy returns cudaErrorInvalidValue for __device__ array

Tags: c, cuda, memcpy

When I define an array on the device (that is initialized with a "Hello" string in this example) and try to copy this to the host, I get the error code `cudaErrorInvalidValue`. However, from inside a kernel, the `d_helloStr[]` can be accessed. Referring to the CUDA programming guide chapter B.2.1, such a variable should also be accessible through the runtime library. Why does this example code not work?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>


__device__ char d_helloStr[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};

// Host function
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  cudaError_t err;
  char h_helloStr [sizeof(d_helloStr)];

  // copy device string to host string: 
  err = cudaMemcpy(h_helloStr, d_helloStr, sizeof(d_helloStr), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("err = %d\n", err);

  // result string:   
  printf("%s\n", h_helloStr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you use cudaMalloc to get the memory for the chars in device?

Comment: That would be the mechanism used in this hello-world demo (which actually works): http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=90044

I also allocated some memory on the device using cudaMalloc, copied the string from the d_helloStr variable to this memory and used cudaMemcpy to copy the string from this memory back to the host. This works also. 

However, I'm wondering why I cannot access the d_helloStr directly via cudaMemcpy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cudaMemcpyFromSymbol.